# Nested System.RuntimeType object changes address automatically

Tags: .net, python.net

I'm loading a class library dll with pythonnet that is based on .NET 4.5, probably written in VB. I can instantiate the the most relevant class (`SDK`), create objects needed as method arguments and call the methods.

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("C7000_SDK")
from C7000 import SDK
import System
sdk = SDK()
sdk.SK_Connect()
```

However, there is one method that requires an object as argument which has nested objects. If I create the object, the address of the inner object changes with every call. I wouldn't care, but the problem is, that I can't assigne values/objects to the members of these nested objects.

```
res = SDK.SKS_MEAS_RESULT()

res.ColorRenditionIndexes
Out[28]: <C7000.SKS_COLOR_RENDERING_INDEX object at 0x0C18D6A0>

res.ColorRenditionIndexes
Out[29]: <C7000.SKS_COLOR_RENDERING_INDEX object at 0x0C18D3B8>
```

I think this address change is the main problem. What I actually need to do is assigne memory for some arrays like so:

```
# Works fine
res.SpectralData_1nm = System.Array[System.Single]([0.0]*SDK.SKF_WAVELENGTH_1NM_COUNT)
res.SpectralData_1nm
Out[31]: <System.Single[] object at 0x0C18D598>

# Doesn't work
res.ColorRenditionIndexes.Ri = System.Array[System.String]([""]*SDK.SKF_CRI_COUNT)
type(res.ColorRenditionIndexes.Ri)
Out[34]: NoneType
```

I wrote a wrapper with C++/CLI where I used the following and it perfectly worked.

```
SDK::SKS_MEAS_RESULT res;
res.SpectralData_1nm = gcnew array<float>(SDK::SKF_WAVELENGTH_1NM_COUNT);
res.ColorRenditionIndexes.Ri = gcnew array<String^>(SDK::SKF_CRI_COUNT);
```

I'm not sure where I'm missing something. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python can not represent C#'s `ref T` type when `T` is a value type. Instead, when you access `res.ColorRenditionIndexes` you get a copy of its value.

A workaround is to assign in 3 steps:

```py
cri = res.ColorRenditionIndexes
cri.Ri = ...
res.ColorRenditionIndexes = cri
```

Comment: Magic, it works perfectly, thank you very much. I wrote a VB wrapper meanwhile to simplify this one call but now I can delete it :)